VH6501 CAN Disturbance interface not starting from CANoe 14
I have VH6501 hardware from Vector connected to CANoe Pro  v14.
For the CAN node I have the "CAN Disturbance Features" checked.
With a simple projekt setup, as CAN 500KBaud and just click start I get the message:
SYSTEM 0.000000: CAN 1: CAN disturbance is enabled, but the hardware interface or the driver does not support the stress feature.
I have the latest driver from Vector's produkt page and CANoe Pro 14.4.13 SP4 - 64bit is a clean installation on Windows 11 64bit. The lisence says Ok and doesn't complain.
If I uncheck "CAN Disturbance Features" it will start.
Can anyone give me some hints on what might be wrong?
PS: There are no tags available for either CAN or CANoe here and I don't have enough rep. to create these. I'm asking about the software CANoe with attached hardware VH6501, not CAN itself.
